# Despite symbols loaded, breakPoints not hit and CallStack frameNames are line0 in python

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, blender

I was debugging python scripts in Blender project with visual studio.

I import a fbx file, but the breakpoints in parse_fbx.py are not hit.
I click the BreakAll button, and vs complains source not found. But if I press the "Browse" button vs can actually find the source file.
[image]

Even After the source file is open in the new tab automatically, breakPoints are not hit.
In callStack the name of frame ends with Line0, maybe this is why breakPoints are not hit?
Right click the frame and "Go to module", the symbols are loaded for import_fbx.py, parse_fbx.py
[image]

I followed this: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Debugging/Python_Visual_Studio

Comment: Those of us following the C++ tag expect to see questions related to C++. Here, you have a question about debugging a Python extension to Blender in Visual Studio. Just because the call stack shows that Blender is written in C++ does _not_ mean your question is related to C++ in any way. Please [edit] the question and remove irrelevant tags, or clarify why they are relevant.